# duplication of displayed information android studio, RecyclerView Adapter notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

First of all, sorry for the bad English, I speak Spanish and use google translator.

The problem is every time I enter to see the complaints, it loads perfectly, but when bolting back and entering again the information is duplicated.

[first admission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXW0S.png)

[on the second admission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWBne.png)

this is the adapter

```
package com.example.denuncia.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.denuncia.R;
import com.example.denuncia.model.Denuncia;

import java.util.List;

public class DenunciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DenunciaAdapter.DenunciaHolder> {
    List<Denuncia> list;
    int layout;
    Activity activity;

    public DenunciaAdapter(List<Denuncia> list, int layaut, Activity activity) {
        this.list = list;
        this.layout = layaut;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DenunciaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
        return new DenunciaHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DenunciaAdapter.DenunciaHolder holder, int position) {
        Denuncia denuncia = list.get(position);

        holder.txttipo.setText(denuncia.getTipo_denuncia());
        holder.txtdireccion.setText(denuncia.getDireccion());
        holder.txtnombre.setText(denuncia.getTitulo_denuncia());
        holder.txtestado.setText(denuncia.getEstado_denuncia());

        Glide.with(activity).load(denuncia.getUrl()).into(holder.imagen);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class DenunciaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtnombre,txtdireccion,txtestado,txttipo;
        ImageView imagen;
        public DenunciaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txttipo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
            txtdireccion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccionDenuncia);
            txtestado = itemView.findViewById(R.id.estadoDenuncia);
            txtnombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreDenuncia);
            imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the service I have

```
package com.example.denuncia.adapter;

import com.example.denuncia.model.Denuncia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DenunciaService {

    public static List<Denuncia> denuncias=new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addDenuncia(Denuncia denuncia){
        denuncias.add(denuncia);
    }
    public static void updateDenuncia(Denuncia denuncia){
        denuncias.set(denuncias.indexOf(denuncia),denuncia);
    }
}
```

This is the class

```
package com.example.denuncia;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.denuncia.adapter.DenunciaAdapter;
import com.example.denuncia.adapter.DenunciaService;
import com.example.denuncia.model.Denuncia;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ver_denuncias extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rc;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_denuncias);
        firebaseAuth        = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        rc = findViewById(R.id.rc);

        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        lm.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        rc.setLayoutManager(lm);

        DenunciaAdapter adapter = new DenunciaAdapter(DenunciaService.denuncias,R.layout.item,this);
        rc.setAdapter(adapter);

        cargaDatosFirebase();
    }


    public void cargaDatosFirebase(){

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Denuncias").child(uid);

        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                Denuncia denuncia = snapshot.getValue(Denuncia.class);

                if (!DenunciaService.denuncias.contains(denuncia)) {
                    DenunciaService.addDenuncia(denuncia);
                }
                    rc.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                Denuncia denuncia = snapshot.getValue(Denuncia.class);
                if (DenunciaService.denuncias.contains(denuncia)) {
                    DenunciaService.updateDenuncia(denuncia);
                }
                rc.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void perfil(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ver_denuncias.this, perfil_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are calling `DenunciaService.addDenuncia(denuncia);` repeatedly and when you navigate back your list contains previously items when `onCreate` method es executed.

So, you have two options:

1. Check if your `denuncias` `List` is empty before call `cargaDatosFirebase`

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //(...)
       //your current code here

       //check if list is empty before load data
       if (DenunciaService.denuncias.size() == 0)
           cargaDatosFirebase();
   }
   ```
2. Try to `clear` your `denuncias` `List` before call `cargaDatosFirebase`.

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //(...)
       //your current code here

       //clear list before load data
       DenunciaService.denuncias.clear();

       cargaDatosFirebase();
   }
   ```

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: clean it this way?                                         
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq1hmyhudps22l4/zzzzz.png?dl=0)

Comment: Yes, `list.clear()` can work, but the adapter isn't the right place.

Comment: Check the answer, I have edited the answer.